# Confusion in submitting Documents for Canada Tourist Visa stamping

Tags: canada, indian-citizens, paperwork, tourist-visas

I am an Indian citizen, presently working in the USA on H1B visa. I have applied for the Canada tourist Visa online from USA and have been asked to provide the passport for further processing

Here are my questions

1. The request from CIC only says to provide passport and the request form. Nowhere has it mentioned to pay the amount for VAC. Is this service required?
2. Also where to send the passport, request form and return envelope in Los Angeles is also not very clear in the CIC website. What is the correct address ?
3. If there is any additional documents that we need to send other than requested in the request letter? Many websites say VAC consent form, VAC payment details, check / DD paid to Utah office for availing VAC services?
4. Why can’t we sent the documents directly to Immigration office instead of Visa Application Office
5. Already CAD100 has been paid during online submission. Does it include the VAC as well?

Answer (score 3):

After you get the letter from CIC, as it says on the letter, you must go to http://www.cic.gc.ca/submit to find out where to submit your passport. It depends on your country of residence, country of application, etc, so read that page carefully.

As you will see from the website above, for some countries you **must** submit the passport to the VAC (instead of directly to the Canadian authorities).

In this case, there will be additional fees to pay (the VAC fee, and if you aren't picking up the passport yourself then also the VAC passport return fee / courier fee). The VAC may also require you to fill additional forms. You should read the VAC site carefully, I suggest calling them if anything is unclear (e.g. the VAC in Russia has a very confusing website, you need to fill out 3 additional forms but it's very unclear that you have to do that unless you read it very carefully). The VAC website will give you the address where you need to send the passport.

The $100 CAD fee you pay for the visa does NOT include the VAC service fee.